# stuttering videos

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video

I recently switched from windows to ubuntu and whenever i play videos it stutters . this happens with both locally stored videos and online streaming sites like youtube , twitch , etc (on all browsers) ,there is no lag in audio.

I installed latest nvidia driver and followed [this](http://sudo%20update-initramfs%20-u) solution to get rid of screen tearing issue

but still screen stuttering issue persisted. i tried almost all solutions from different forums . even tried rolling back to older version of nvidia drivers but none of them worked for me :(

This is the screenshot from
[neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjc5N.png)

i am noob please let me know if i missed to add some info .

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope. Had to switch back to windows :/